# Posting data to MVC Controller using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple html form with 2 textboxes and a button as following:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="GetStudentController">
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Index</h2>
            <input id="Text1" class="form-group form-control" ng-model="ime" type="text" />


            <input id="Text1" class="form-group form-control" ng-model="prezime" type="text" />

            <input type="button" style="float:right;" class="form-group btn btn-primary" ng-click="snimi(ime,prezime)" value="Snimi" />
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is my AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service("GetStudentsService", function ($http) {
    this.getData = function ()
    {
        return $http({
            metod: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetStudent"
        }).success(function (data) {
            return data;
        }).error(function () {
            alert("error");
            return null;
        });
    }
    this.PostData = function (data)
    {
        $http.post("/Home/SnimiStudenta",data)    
        .success(function () {
            getData();
        }).error(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
});
app.controller("GetStudentController", function ($scope, GetStudentsService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    GetStudentsService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });
    $scope.snimi = function (ime, prezime) {
        var data = $.param({
            fName: ime,
            lName: prezime
        });
        GetStudentsService.PostData(data);
    };

});
```

And this is the action responsible for saving the record to the DB:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void SnimiStudenta(// I would like to pass an Student object here)
        {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.Ime = "1";
            s.Prezime = "2";
            Connection.dc.Students.Add(s);
            Connection.dc.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I have a few questions:

- How can I mark my values from my textboxes and pass them as an Student object into my action
- How can I bind the table upon saving the new record into the DB. As you can see I'm calling the function getData(); but it says its undefined...

Can someone help me out with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build a js object which looks similar to your C# class (In terms of the property name) which you use as the parameter for your action method, and post the js object

```
$scope.snimi = function (ime, prezime) {
    var data = { Ime: ime, Prezime: prezime};
    GetStudentsService.PostData(data);
};
```

And your action method,

```
[HttpPost]
public void SnimiStudenta(Student s)
{
    Connection.dc.Students.Add(s);
    Connection.dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that part worked :) But how to bind the table (refresh it) when data is posted and saved to the db?? .success(function () { getData();

Comment: You can even return some response (some JSON data which indicates the action was successful) and upon checking the response, you can use the js object you posted to update your UI.  or you can just make a new GET call (like you are doing now) and get data.

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you ment please ? :) do you mean like $http.get(url); ?? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as why you get an "undefined" error when you call `getData()`, it is not because `getData` is undefined, but because `getData` returns a promise containing just the data, not the whole response. So change:

```
 GetStudentsService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
 });
```

to:

```
GetStudentsService.getData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
 });
```

Comment: Okay but how to bind the table (refresh it) when data is posted and saved to the db??         .success(function () { getData();